# Assigning Xeon-Phi to MPI process

Tags: mpi, hpc, acceleration, intel-mic, xeon-phi

My system has two xeon-phi cards attached to one single node. I am trying to run a distributed MPI code, that uses xeon-phi acceleration in offload mode. I am wondering if I run two MPI process per node, how would I assign xeon-phi to each MPI process. How do I ensure that it is each MPI process is using a different MIC.

Comment: Just FYI, many white papers with user-case scenarios about Intel Xeon Phi Coprocessors can be found here: (http://research.colfaxinternational.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
int rank;
...
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
...
#pragma offload target(mic:rank)
{
    //offloaded code
}
```

So, the idea is to get the MPI rank number, and then use it to assign offload to specific MIC device. If you will have more than 2 MPI processes this construction still can be used, but you need to assign two neighboring MPI processes to the same host.

Comment: SOmething similar to this I am trying.